# jQuery not recognizing class selector but works without it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class="track_this" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google</a>
```

WORKS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("a").click(function() {
    $.post("http://example.com/clk.php",{URL:this.href});
    return true;
  });
});
```

DOES NOT WORK:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".track_this").click(function() {
    $.post("http://example.com/clk.php",{URL:this.href});
    return true;
  });
});
```

Very frustrating. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You generally want to avoid underscores in class and id names. Try a hyphen instead.

Comment: Both code works..I mean, the click event it's called. https://jsfiddle.net/lbclucascosta/8bdq6p54/

Comment: @Gavin underscores, though annoying to type, are perfectly valid

Comment: @DelightedD0D I did not say they were invalid. I said `You generally want to avoid underscores ...` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names

Comment: How are you asserting that it "does not work"?  Have you *tried* the code you posted, as-is, without any other code?  Such as here: https://jsfiddle.net/gt6zyLfy/  **works fine**.   You must have some other code or this is *not* your actual scenario.

Comment: @Gavin sure, but then you said "*Try a hyphen instead.*" implying that changing from an underscore to a hyphen might somehow fix the issue. It wouldnt. Both are perfectly valid. It would be like changing the selector to `.track_that`.... superfluous. Just making sure the OP understands that's not a thing

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to **reproduce** it in the question itself."  **Your code does not reproduce the problem.**

Comment: I am literally changing "a" to ".track_this" and changing nothing else yet it does not work when changed to ".track_this". I understand how silly this looks and it is the reason I am so frustrated. I was maybe hoping for a suggestion for troubleshooting it rather than the obvious fact that the code should work as-is. I do appreciate the input, though.

Comment: @Gavin That's 15 years old. It says **the following recommendation is no longer accurate for most circumstances.**

Comment: @JeffGriffiths Since you don't return `false` or call `event.preventDefault()`, clicking on the link will cause the link to be followed. This may cancel the AJAX call. I can't explain why it matters whether you use a tag or class, but either way you need to deal with that.

Comment: **1.** Try to recreate the issue (done twice here), confirmed as not the problem as described, so must be another issue.  **2.** either rebuild your app (from the recreation) by adding code until the issue occurs OR remove code from your app until the issue no longer occurs (generally easier).   **3** use the browser console to test selectors.  **4** add debugging to your code either with console.log or alert.  **5** step through your code in the console browser.

Comment: Please elaborate on "does not work" - put an alert inside the handler, is that called?

Comment: Please confirm which browser(s) you have tried this on, specifically, **are you using IE5** (possibly stupid question, but see previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is incredibly stupid but I made the assumption that the class="track_this" was actually being passed to my anchor tag when it actually was not.

It appears that the content management system (Wordpress) was stripping the class because of how I was formatting the HTML.

```
<a class="track_this" href="http://google.com">google</a> was stripping the class.
```

and

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="track_this">google.com</a> does not strip the class
```

I have no idea why this is. Thanks to all who took time out of their day for such a silly question and apologies for not being more thorough in my analysis.